# Preflight error on Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I'm facing a preflight error when I try to call a cloud function of mine from my website. I implemented the cors module in my cloud function, and my request got the cors header authorizations

The cloud function :

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
exports.CLOUDFUNCTION = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request: any, response: any) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {
      response.status(200).send('hello');
    })
  }
);
```

The website request :

```
fetch('FIREBASE_URL/CLOUDFUNCTION',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization'
               
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body), // body is a simple {"variable": "value"}
          }
        );
```

The error

```
Access to fetch at 'FIREBASE_URL/CLOUDFUNCTION' from origin 'MYWEBSITE' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: When you open `FIREBASE_URL/CLOUDFUNCTION` in a browser, do you also get an error?

Comment: you mean if i type it directly in my search bar ? Cause I got a 403 error if I directly try to access it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are getting a 403 Forbidden Error when trying to access your function via it's URL, you have a problem with your function's deployment, it's configuration or you have made a mistake in the URL.

**Note:** While I use "traditional" `require` statements here to match your example, I encourage you to use newer ES6+ JavaScript features (`const`, `let`, `async`/`await`, `import`, etc.) for any newly written functions.

#### Deploy using the latest `firebase-tools` version

Make sure you are deploying using the latest version of the `firebase-tools` CLI.

When `v7.7.0` of `firebase-tools` released (Jan 15, 2020), the way Cloud Functions are invoked on the server changed so that functions could be invoked by only authenticated users. To be accessible to Firebase Users, these functions must be made public by explicitly granting the `allUsers` group the *Cloud Function Invoker* permission.

In `v7.7.0` and later, this is done for you as part of deployment. However, if you deploy functions using an older version, you will need to [configure this permission yourself](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation) or redeploy using a newer `firebase-tools` version.

#### Check the exported function name

Make sure the function you export is named what you expect once deployed.

In particular, pay close attention to when your function is exported as part of a [function group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#group_functions) either deliberately or accidentally. This often turns up when you've split your functions into multiple files. In the below code blocks, `CLOUDFUNCTION` gets exported as `myFunctions-CLOUDFUNCTION` and not just `CLOUDFUNCTION` as you may expect.

```
// myFunctions.js
exports.CLOUDFUNCTION = functions.https.onRequest(...);
```

```
// index.js (incorrect)
exports.myFunctions = require("./myFunctions.js");
```

```
// index.js (correct)
const myFunctions = require("./myFunctions.js");

exports.CLOUDFUNCTION = myFunctions.CLOUDFUNCTION;
```

#### Check the function's URL

Check the Cloud Functions URL you are using for typos. Function names in Cloud Functions URLs are case-sensitive.

The correct URL should follow the format:

```
https://<REGION>-<PROJECT_ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<EXPORTED_FUNCTION_NAME>
```

Example:

```
https://us-central1-fir-sandbox.cloudfunctions.net/echo
```

#### Handle CORS errors & stop processing

In your code example, you pass in the `NextFunction` without an error handler. While using `{ origin: true }`, this is "fine", but you'll start running into trouble when you start restricting the origins you call your function from. This is particularly handy for preventing your functions being invoked directly by their URL (where `origin` would be `undefined`). Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin) or the next section for more info.

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
exports.CLOUDFUNCTION = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => { // <-- don't use `: any` here, as you are disabling the built-in types provided by firebase-functions
    cors(request, response, async (err) => {
      if (err) {
        // Denied by CORS/error with CORS configuration
        console.error("CORS blocked request -> ", err);
        response.status(403).send("Forbidden by CORS");
        return;
      }

      response.status(200).send('hello');
    })
  }
);
```

#### Optional: Tighten the `cors` configuration

While you can reflect the `Access-Control-*` headers using the `cors` package, consider explicitly setting these server-side.

```
const { projectId: PROJECT_ID } = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

const cors = require('cors')({
  // during emulation, allow localhost & calling directly (i.e. no origin specified);
  // at all other times, restrict to deployed hosting sites only
  origin: process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === "true"
    ? /^(https?:\/\/localhost:\d+|undefined)$/
    : [`https://${PROJECT_ID}.firebaseapp.com`, `https://${PROJECT_ID}.web.app`],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
});

exports.CLOUDFUNCTION = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, async (err) => {
      if (err) {
        // Denied by CORS/error with CORS configuration
        console.error("CORS blocked request -> ", err);
        response.status(403).send("Forbidden by CORS");
        return;
      }

      response.status(200).send('hello');
    })
  }
);
```

This simplifies your client-side code:

```
fetch('FIREBASE_URL/CLOUDFUNCTION',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  }
);
```

#### Optional: Use Callable Functions

If your functions will require you to do actions on behalf of a user, you could make use of [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) instead of the more bare-bones HTTPS Request functions. This version of a HTTPS Function handles CORS, authentication, and supports Promise-based returning of data.

Note: This will still require the function to be public as described above.

On the server side:

```
exports.CLOUDFUNCTION = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    // users must be logged in
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition',
      'The function must be called while authenticated.'
    );
  }

  if (data.variable === undefined)) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'invalid-argument',
      'Parameter "variable" must be a string'
    );
  }

  // you can return a promise here
  // this sends back the JSON string "hello world"
  return "hello world";
});
```

On the client side:

```
const callFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('CLOUDFUNCTION');

callFunction(body)
  .then(
    (responseData) => {
      // TODO: handle response
    },
    (functionError) => {
      // TODO: handle error
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer that was incredibly complet. What you said on the `Cloud Function Invoker permission` made me tried all my cloud functions (that all had the same parameters, and only this one answered with a 403. 
I created a new cloud function (I created a new function and copy pasted the legacy code to the new function and switched my call/ It work at the end of the day. I believe something went wrong when I created my previous function with `firebase deploy --only functions:MYCLOUDFUNCTION`. 
Again, thank you so much for your time and support. Really appreciated

Comment: I recently deployed a new function with firebase tools v13.1.0 and it failed to add the allUsers permission. I remember this from years ago, but haven't seen recently. Also - this was a 2nd Gen function, and the fix is slightly different (or at least theres a simpler way), In the Function control panelt, Under "..." menu, "Go To Cloud Run Service", then Security > Authentication > Allow unauthenticated invocations "Tick this if you are creating a public API or website."
It then adds the IAM for you. It's nice and simple.