# CORS error with 2nd gen Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying the [2nd generation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/version-comparison) Cloud Functions for Firebase. I have `makeUppercase()` firing with `onDocumentCreated()`. Now I'm trying to get an Angular app to call a callable cloud function.

*index.ts*

```js
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { defineSecret } from "firebase-functions/params";
const apiKey = defineSecret("12345abcde");
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
initializeApp();

export const CallUppercaseMe2ndGen = onCall({ secrets: [apiKey] }, (request) => {
    if (request.data != undefined) {
        if (request.auth != undefined) {
            const text = request.data.text;
            const uid = request.auth.uid;
            logger.log("Uppercasing", uid, text);
            const uppercase = text.toUpperCase();
            return uppercase;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

*angular.component.ts*

```js
async callMe() {
    const upperCaseMe = httpsCallable(this.functions, 'CallUppercaseMe2ndGen');
    // const upperCaseMe = httpsCallableFromURL(this.functions, 'http://localhost:5001/my-project/us-central1/CallUppercaseMe2ndGen');
    // const upperCaseMe = httpsCallableFromURL(this.functions, 'https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/CallUppercaseMe2ndGen');
    upperCaseMe({
      text: 'hello world',
    })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

This throws a CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1/my-project.cloudfunctions.net/CallUppercaseMe2ndGen' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I know a few ways to fix a CORS error in a cloud function.

1. Use an IAM service account. This is my preference in 1st generation cloud functions. In the 2nd generation cloud function I put in my API key. I suspect the problem is that I need to put in more than the API key to connect a cloud function to an IAM service account. How do I do this?
2. Set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in `firebase.json`. This works in a deployed cloud function but not in the emulator.
3. Import `cors` with `onRequest`. This works with `onRequest`, not with `onCall`. I don't use HTTP requests to call cloud functions.
4. Use `httpsCallableFromURL` instead of `httpsCallable`. Doug Stevenson has discouraged me from this solution but it sometimes fixes the CORS error.
5. New in the 2nd generation cloud functions, you can [configure CORS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd) in `onRequest`. I'm using `onCall`, not `onRequest`. I tried replacing the parameter `{secrets: [apiKey]}` with `{cors: true}` but that didn't help.

On request I'll show code for each of these five solutions.

Comment: Have you [connected to the functions emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/functions.md#connectfunctionsemulator) as needed? What page are you presented with when you visit the Cloud Function in a browser? What status code does it return? Often CORS errors mask other error codes like Error 404 or Error 500.

Comment: For solution #1, I am curious how IAM (authorization) solves your CORS problem. Adding the authorization header does not bypass CORS for requests made from a browser.

Comment: @JohnHanley, with my first generation cloud functions I set up the IAM service account and I no longer saw CORS errors. You're right, I have no idea how a service account fixes CORS errors, other than magic. :-)

Comment: @samthecodingman, at your suggestion I added `connectFunctionsEmulator(this.functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);` to the top of my Angular function. That didn't fix the CORS error. When I go to the Cloud Function URL the browser shows "Not found" without a code.

Comment: I just encountered the same issue after upgrading my `onCall()` functions to 2nd generation. Still have not found a solution :(

Comment: last time I checked 'firebase functions' was 'node.js'. You need to add headers object with *`access-control-allow-origin: *`*

Answer (score 3):

I didn't say that the CORS errors were thrown when I was using the emulator, not the cloud. Everything is working now. I did two things:

1. I deployed my functions to the Firebase cloud. The first deployment ended with an error message saying that Firebase had to configure stuff for 2nd gen cloud functions. The next deployment went through and my functions worked in the cloud.
2. I added this code at the top of the Angular handler function:

```js
connectFunctionsEmulator(this.functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);
```

This code makes the function run in the emulator. Commenting it out makes the function run in the cloud.

The CORS errors were thrown because my Angular app was trying to call the functions in the cloud, but the functions hadn't been deployed to the cloud. I hadn't put in `connectFunctionsEmulator()` so the functions weren't running in the emulator.

In other words, the CORS error were a red herring that sent me down a rabbit hole. If the error had said, "No such function found in the Firebase cloud and no emulator is connected," I would've figured out the error quickly.

I tried the same function with `{ secrets: [apiKey]`, with `{ cors: true }`, and with neither. All three worked.

Comment: Unfortunately when a `fetch` API call fails because the CORS preflight check fails, the error returned is `TypeError: failed to fetch` with no further information. While I agree a helper error message would be beneficial, its something that should not be encountered in production and thus is not part of the SDK as it would be never invoked. Instead its left as an exercise for the developer to resolve.

Comment: For future readers, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67323936/3068190) for other things to look out for.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. I'm not sure which one of these actions (or all of them) solved the problem, but here's what I did.

1. [Specify a region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade#set_runtime_options).

   ```
   import { setGlobalOptions } from 'firebase-functions/v2'

   // locate all functions closest to users
   setGlobalOptions({ region: "us-central1" })
   ```
2. Create a **newly named function** that's just a copy of your previous function, but includes `{cors: true}`

   ```
   export const myFunctionCopy = onCall({ cors: true }, async (request) => 
   {
   ...
   }
   ```
3. Point your front-end code to this newly named function accordingly.
4. Deploy

I suspect there's some sort of cache / propagation issue going on with Google's backend. Renaming the function (as opposed to just updating the code) avoids this.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Reading the documentation, it looks like `{ cors: true }` is only for `onRequest` functions. "Additionally, some triggers have convenient new configuration features, like the onRequest trigger's cors option." https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade#update_trigger_definitions

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear this didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed for me by going to the cloud function in google console, and if its a v2 function, it needs Cloud Run Invoker, "allUsers" or "allAuthenticatedUsers". I had thought it would be okay if it was a "Functions Invoker", but they have migrated it to Cloud Run.

Comment: This solution is a side-effect. When authorization is required, IAP returns an HTTP status error. You must enable CORS in IAP so that the browser reports the actual error instead of a blind CORS error.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case `allUsers` since I need my function to be available to anyone (meeting certain requirements, for example being authenticated). I haven't gotten any CORS errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my emulated callable functions.

In addition to making sure you're connecting to the emulator i.e.
`connectFunctionsEmulator(this.functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);`

You'll need to make sure the function you're trying to call is part of the latest build. This means the function has to be defined in your latest build: `functions/lib/index.js`.

If it isn't in your latest build, you may simply run `npm run build` from the **/functions** directory to rebuild your functions and try calling the function once again.